# Replace attribute value in XML (attrubute path variable)

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument, xmlreader

I'm working with an XML document that contains a structure that looks similar to this:

```
<SW.Blocks.OB ID="$">
<AttributeList>
<ObjectList>
  <MultilingualText ID="$" CompositionName="Comment">
    <ObjectList>
      <MultilingualTextItem ID="$" CompositionName="Items">
        <AttributeList>
          <Culture>en-US</Culture>
          <Text />
        </AttributeList>
      </MultilingualTextItem>
      <MultilingualTextItem ID="$" CompositionName="Items">
        <AttributeList>
          <Culture>nl-NL</Culture>
          <Text />
        </AttributeList>
      </MultilingualTextItem>
      <MultilingualTextItem ID="$" CompositionName="Items">
        <AttributeList>
          <Culture>de-DE</Culture>
          <Text />
        </AttributeList>
      </MultilingualTextItem>
    </ObjectList>
  </MultilingualText>
</ObjectList>
</SW.Blocks.OB>
```

I'm searching for the attribute ID. This attribute can occur everywhere.
I already can find the value of those ID's

```
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(@"Main.xml");
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            reader.MoveToContent();
            string test = reader.GetAttribute("ID");

            if (test == "$")
            {
             MessageBox.Show(test);
            } 
        }
```

But I can't change them. 
Goal: Find ID, no matter where, and replace the value of that attibute with a 'value'.

Who could help me out? I already tried Xdocument and Xmldocument as well. I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication13
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<XElement> ids = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Attribute("ID") != null).ToList();

            int indNo = 1;
            foreach (XElement id in ids)
            {
                id.Attribute("ID").SetValue(indNo++);
            }



        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Thankyou for this solution. This solution works for me!

Answer (score -1):

I believe it would be easier to use `XmlDocument` and `XPathNavigator`

You load your document and then navigate over it using XPath and then change the value you need.

For example::

```
XmlDocument _soapEnvelopeXml = new XmlDocument();
_soapEnvelopeXml.Load(".xml");
XPathNavigator _xmlNav = _soapEnvelopeXml.FirstChild.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode(WebServiceEnum.MAIN_CIL_TAG);

        _xmlNav.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("*[local-name()='BUID']").SetValue(buid);
        _xmlNav.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("*[local-name()='CustomerNumber']").SetValue(customerNum);
```